# Azure CostMangement API "nextLink" field not returning pagination data

Tags: azure

I am using the CostMgmt API from Azure using bearer token. I am able to get the first response properly.

But there is a nextLink field with a URL which i am trying to use to read the next pages.

But when i try to access the URL with the correct headers(bearer token) and the nextLink URL i get the following error message. Not sure if we have a working example using nextLink.

I also tried using get method in requests which gave me error saying ('{"message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}') so i had to use post method which gave me the error as mentioned.
The nextlink URL has the following format.

nextlink = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2019-11-01&$skiptoken=BQBBBB%3D%3D"

response2 = requests.post(nextlink,headers=default_headers)

{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Invalid query definition, Dataset is invalid or not supplied. (Request ID: 72778dac-XXXX-XXXX)"}}'

Appreciate any kind of guidance.

Comment: This post appears to be off topic. Programming questions should be asked on [so].

Answer (score 1):

I was able resolve the issue by using the same jsonbody that is used for the parentlink and the method needs to be POST ,using a while loop for looping through all the nextlinks.
Hopefully this information will be helpful.